# Retrieve a multipart/form-data file as XML nodes

Tags: marklogic

I have a problem with a form, that I could narrow down to the
following.  It is a POST of type multipart/form data, sending one file
part:

```
------------------------------ed0cb8f98262
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="example.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

<hello>World!</hello>

------------------------------ed0cb8f98262--
```

When I use `xdmp:get-request-field('file')` to get te value, it is
returned as a document node containing one text node.  If I change
`text/plain` to `application/octet-stream`, the value is a binary
node.

I would have expected a document node with an element `hello`.  The
following query reproduces the problem (accessing and outputing a few
key values, to double-check my environment):

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" 
   at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

declare namespace xdmp = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp";
declare namespace mt   = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/mimetypes";

declare function local:type-from-filename($name as xs:string) as xs:string*
{
   let $ext   := fn:tokenize($name, '\.')[fn:last()]
   let $types := admin:mimetypes-get(admin:get-configuration())
   return
      $types[mt:extensions/data() = $ext]/mt:name
};

<fields version="{ xdmp:version() }">
{
   for $name     in xdmp:get-request-field-names()
   let $value    := xdmp:get-request-field($name)
   let $filename := xdmp:get-request-field-filename($name)
   return
      <field>
         <name>{ $name }</name>
         <is-text>{ $value/node() instance of text() }</is-text>
         <is-binary>{ $value/node() instance of binary() }</is-binary>
         <filename type="{ local:type-from-filename($filename) }">{ $filename }</filename>
         <content-type>{ xdmp:get-request-field-content-type($name) }</content-type>
         {
            if ( $value instance of binary() ) then
               <value>...binary...</value>
            else
               <value>{ $value }</value>
         }
      </field>
}
</fields>
```

When called with the following CURL command (just put the above query
on a HTTP app server, and adapt the user, password, and endpoint
below):

```
curl -u user:pwd --digest \
    -F "file=@.../example.xml;type=text/xml" \
    http://localhost:8010/test/tools/fields
```

it returns the following:

```
<fields version="8.0-4">
   <field>
      <name>file</name>
      <is-text>true</is-text>
      <is-binary>false</is-binary>
      <filename type="application/xml">example.xml</filename>
      <content-type>text/xml</content-type>
      <value>&lt;hello&gt;World!&lt;/hello&gt; </value>
   </field>
</fields>
```

When called with the following CURL command (note the different
type=):

```
curl -u user:pwd --digest \
    -F "file=@.../example.xml;type=application/octet-stream" \
    http://localhost:8010/test/tools/fields
```

it returns the following:

```
<fields version="8.0-4">
   <field>
      <name>file</name>
      <is-text>false</is-text>
      <is-binary>false</is-binary>
      <filename type="application/xml">example.xml</filename>
      <content-type>application/octet-stream</content-type>
      <value>...binary...</value>
   </field>
</fields>
```

Did I miss something?  Shouldn't I get an XML document node?

Question posted on MarkLogic [dev mailing
list](http://marklogic.markmail.org/thread/4g6tpnldmtue5pd4) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [xdmp:unquote()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:unquote) on the text representation of the XML to turn it into a document node.

Comment: Well, sure, but, ahem, you know, it sounds like a defect to me (a regression, even?) Am I guaranteed I always receive it as text? Or as binary? Or...?

Comment: Not sure.;  I've always used xdmp:unquote for this purpose.

Comment: Well.. the function signature says that it returns item()*.  Nothing about that suggests that it will parse the content of any field in a milti-part form for you.  The only mention at all is regarding binary.  JSON, XML - we always have to handle these ourselves.  It would be  a regression issue or bug  if you could show that it used to work another way. Just not working as one would intuitively expect is not necessarily and indication of either bug or regression isssue.  Is there a version of ML in which you noticed this working differently?